# How to Improve performance of apply function for more than 5 millions rows?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, performance, vectorization

I have one minute OHLCV data from 2006 to 2022. There are more than 5 millions rows. From the one minute data I made 5 minute and 30 minute data like its calculated every minute the new high and low for 5 minutes data. Below is the example of the 5 minute data and the code. But It takes huge time for running. Is there any way to vectorize it efficient way or any other solution.

```
                                                         Open        High         Low        Close
                        0                        Date

2006-04-13 10:15:00-04:00   2006-04-13 10:15:00-04:00   1914.75     1915.0      1913.75     1913.75
                            2006-04-13 10:16:00-04:00   1914.00     1915.0      1913.25     1913.75
                            2006-04-13 10:17:00-04:00   1913.75     1915.0      1912.50     1913.00
                            2006-04-13 10:18:00-04:00   1912.75     1915.0      1912.50     1913.00
                            2006-04-13 10:19:00-04:00   1913.00     1915.0      1912.50     1913.75
2006-04-13 10:20:00-04:00   2006-04-13 10:20:00-04:00   1913.75     1913.75     1912.75     1912.75
                            2006-04-13 10:21:00-04:00   1912.75     1913.75     1911.50     1911.75
                            2006-04-13 10:22:00-04:00   1911.75     1913.75     1911.50     1912.25
                            2006-04-13 10:23:00-04:00   1912.50     1913.75     1911.50     1912.25
                            2006-04-13 10:24:00-04:00   1912.50     1913.75     1911.25     1912.25
2006-04-13 10:25:00-04:00   2006-04-13 10:25:00-04:00   1912.50     1912.75     1912.00     1912.75
                            2006-04-13 10:26:00-04:00   1912.50     1912.75     1911.00     1911.50
    ...                             ...                   ...         ...         ...         ...
    ...                             ...                   ...         ...         ...         ...
    ...                             ...                   ...         ...         ...         ...
2022-04-29 16:55:00-04:00   2022-04-29 16:55:00-04:00   12886.50    12890.0     12885.00    12888.75
                            2022-04-29 16:56:00-04:00   12888.25    12890.0     12885.00    12889.00
                            2022-04-29 16:57:00-04:00   12889.25    12891.5     12885.00    12888.75
                            2022-04-29 16:58:00-04:00   12888.75    12892.5     12885.00    12890.00
                            2022-04-29 16:59:00-04:00   12889.50    12892.5     12885.00    12890.50
```

```
# Importing libraries
import pandas as pd
import pandas_ta as pt

def ttm_5_30min(np_array, ohlc5, ohlc30):

    ohlc5min = ohlc5.loc[:np_array.name].groupby(level=0).agg({'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last'}).iloc[-6:]
    ohlc30min = ohlc30.loc[:ohlc30.loc[:,np_array.name[1],:].index[0]].groupby(level=0).agg({'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last'}).iloc[-6:]

    try:
        ttm5 = pt.ttm_trend(ohlc5min['High'], ohlc5min['Low'], ohlc5min['Close']).iloc[-1,0]
    except:
        ttm5 = np.nan
    try:
        ttm30 = pt.ttm_trend(ohlc30min['High'], ohlc30min['Low'], ohlc30min['Close']).iloc[-1,0]
    except:
        ttm30 = np.nan
    return [ttm5, ttm30]

# ohlc_5min_mark --> 5 Minutes data
# ohlc_5min_mark --> 30 Minutes data

# ttm data for every minutes for 5 and 30 minutes timeframe
ttm_5_30 = pd.DataFrame(ohlc_5min_mark.apply(
     lambda x: ttm_5_30min(x, ohlc_5min_mark, ohlc_30min_mark),
     axis=1,result_type='expand')).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Edit:
One Minute Data:

```
{'Close': {Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1913.75,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:16:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1913.75,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:17:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1913.0,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:18:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1913.0,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:19:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1913.75,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1912.75,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:21:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1911.75,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:22:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1912.25,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:23:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1912.25,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:24:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1912.25},
 'High': {Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1915.0,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:16:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1914.25,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:17:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1913.75,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:18:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1913.25,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:19:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1913.75,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1913.75,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:21:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1912.75,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:22:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1912.25,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:23:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1913.0,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:24:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1912.75},
 'Low': {Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1913.75,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:16:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1913.25,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:17:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1912.5,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:18:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1912.75,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:19:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1913.0,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1912.75,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:21:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1911.5,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:22:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1911.5,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:23:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1912.0,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:24:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1911.25},
 'Open': {Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1914.75,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:16:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1914.0,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:17:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1913.75,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:18:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1912.75,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:19:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1913.0,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1913.75,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:21:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1912.75,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:22:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1911.75,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:23:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1912.5,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:24:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 1912.5},
 'Volume': {Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 415,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:16:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 2604,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:17:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 2042,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:18:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 659,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:19:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 686,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 573,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:21:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 709,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:22:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 400,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:23:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 440,
  Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:24:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'): 725}}
```

From one minute data to ohlc_5min_mark.head(10).to_dict() :

```
{'Close': {(Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1913.75,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:16:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1913.75,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:17:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1913.0,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:18:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1913.0,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:19:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1913.75,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1912.75,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:21:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1911.75,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:22:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1912.25,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:23:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1912.25,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:24:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1912.25},
 'High': {(Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1915.0,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:16:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1915.0,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:17:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1915.0,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:18:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1915.0,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:19:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1915.0,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1913.75,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:21:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1913.75,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:22:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1913.75,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:23:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1913.75,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:24:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1913.75},
 'Low': {(Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1913.75,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:16:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1913.25,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:17:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1912.5,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:18:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1912.5,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:19:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1912.5,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1912.75,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:21:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1911.5,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:22:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1911.5,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:23:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1911.5,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:24:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1911.25},
 'Open': {(Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1914.75,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:16:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1914.0,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:17:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1913.75,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:18:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1912.75,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:15:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:19:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1913.0,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1913.75,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:21:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1912.75,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:22:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1911.75,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:23:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1912.5,
  (Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:20:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'),
   Timestamp('2006-04-13 10:24:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')): 1912.5}}
```

```
# First 10 rows of 5 minutes data for every minute
ohlc_5min_mark.head(10)

Output:
                                                         Open        High        Low         Close
                        0                        Date

2006-04-13 10:15:00-04:00   2006-04-13 10:15:00-04:00   1914.75     1915.00     1913.75     1913.75
                            2006-04-13 10:16:00-04:00   1914.00     1915.00     1913.25     1913.75
                            2006-04-13 10:17:00-04:00   1913.75     1915.00     1912.50     1913.00
                            2006-04-13 10:18:00-04:00   1912.75     1915.00     1912.50     1913.00
                            2006-04-13 10:19:00-04:00   1913.00     1915.00     1912.50     1913.75
2006-04-13 10:20:00-04:00   2006-04-13 10:20:00-04:00   1913.75     1913.75     1912.75     1912.75
                            2006-04-13 10:21:00-04:00   1912.75     1913.75     1911.50     1911.75
                            2006-04-13 10:22:00-04:00   1911.75     1913.75     1911.50     1912.25
                            2006-04-13 10:23:00-04:00   1912.50     1913.75     1911.50     1912.25
                            2006-04-13 10:24:00-04:00   1912.50     1913.75     1911.25     1912.25
# This example will show how values are changing in iterations  
# Using First 9 rows for calculating High Low Close
ohlc_5min_mark.head(9).groupby(level=0).agg({'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last'})

Output:

                             High        Low     Close
                        0
            
2006-04-13 10:15:00-04:00   1915.00     1912.5  1913.75
2006-04-13 10:20:00-04:00   1913.75     1911.5  1912.25
# Using First 10 rows for calculating High Low Close
ohlc_5min_mark.head(10).groupby(level=0).agg({'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last'})

Output:
                             High        Low        Close
                        0
            
2006-04-13 10:15:00-04:00   1915.00     1912.50     1913.75
2006-04-13 10:20:00-04:00   1913.75     1911.25     1912.25
```

Comment: Please provide a small sample of your data using `ohlc_5min_mark.head(10).to_dict()`

Comment: That last line triggers me, and is not what `apply` was built for (really) - so much is going on in there. Do each step separately, then an optimisation may become clear.

Comment: @not_speshal Thank you. I edited my post with small sample

Comment: Your comment in your code says `ohlc_5min_mark` is 5 minute data. Why are you again calculating `ohlc5min` in your function? Also why are you applying the `ttm_trend` function on just 6 rows at a time?

Comment: ```ohlc_5min_mark``` is 5 minute data where it shows how 5 minutes data changes in every minute. For calculating TTM I need to calculating 5 minutes data from ```ohlc_5min_mark```. I need only 6 rows for calculating TTM. I think I need to add a example in my post.

Comment: How quickly to you expect it to be possible to run? Why?

Comment: @not_speshal I add an example. I need to iterate over ohlc_5min_mark for desired value. In real time 5 minute data's High Low Close is updated every seconds for the current 5 minute. I have used this logic here. I need to calculate TTM trend for every minute of 5 minute data

Comment: @KarlKnechtel last time it was running for 25 hours but did not finish running. I stopped it after 25 hours. I think it needs more than 100 hours. If it is finished within 4 to 5 hours it will be better

Comment: In plain English, what is the calculation you are trying to perform?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am trying to calculate TTM for every minute based on 5 minute OHLCV. For calculating TTM based on 5 minute time-frame we need last 6 rows of high and close. Suppose we want to calculate TTM on 10AM we need 10:00, 9:55, 9:50, 9:45, 9:40, 9:35am's high, low and close. For calculating 10am's OHLCV of 5 minute time-frame  we need OHLCV data for 10:00 to 10:04:59. In real time OHLCV may be updated every moment between 10:00 and 1:04:59 and so our TTM could be updated every moment. I need this every moment TTM. In my case moment is 1 minute.

Comment: I have calculated every minute OHLC based on 5 minute OHLCV in ```ohlc_5min_mark```

Answer (score 0):

You can try utilizing a GPU, if you have one.

I have encountered similar problems in numpy matrix and switched to CuPy (CuPu = Numpy + GPU). So I believe a similar solution exists here. Only I am not familiar with CuDF (Pandas + GPU), the syntax looks almost the same as Pandas.

Also I believe the improvement factor is at least 10 if not a hundred.

https://towardsdatascience.com/heres-how-you-can-speedup-pandas-with-cudf-and-gpus-9ddc1716d5f2

https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/pandas-dataframe-tutorial-beginners-guide-to-gpu-accelerated-dataframes-in-python/

Comment: Thank you. I have no GPU. I will try it on Google Colab GPU. They provide GPU.

Comment: Please use sagemaker studio lab to install and use RAPIDS atm, if you want to try it out.